# Class design issue to extend CodeIgniter's Models

Tags: php, codeigniter, design-patterns, model, abstraction

This question is quite specific and long, and deals with **extending CodeIgniter's models**. It's not vital (my application works currently) but I'm asking this because I'm wondering if there is a "clean" way to do this.

I rencently wrote a [blog post](http://sheljohn.blogspot.fr/2013/06/on-template-like-methods-in-php.html) about a trick I'm using to **make CRUD methods generic** for my models. Because I'm only using the "database" library when models are involved, I extended the core Model (MY_Model) to simply load database from its constructor rather than autoload it. It's not a big deal to autoload it, but the point is (and it's important for what follows); I might want to use this constructor to perform other things in the future, so there *needs* to be a constructor.

When I though about making the CRUD methods generic, I thought about using MY_Model again, and was able to define "create", "update", "delete", and "load_from_id" methods successfully. However, these methods rely implicitely on an **interface**, or set of methods that need to be defined in any model (in addition to the static/constant parameters override, for example some validation, or a function to be called on delete to cascade specific consequences in the DB). Two solutions; use PHP **interfaces** or make MY_Model **abstract** and declare abstract methods.

The solution 2 cannot be implemented, because I need a valid contructor in MY_Model, and in any case, I need to be able to call CI_Model's constructor (even if there's nothing in it so far, I can't assume there never will be). In this case, the inheritance stack would be (concrete [`CI_Model`], abstract [`MY_Model`], concrete [`Any_model`]), and I would need to "skip a generation" when calling `parent::__construct();` from my concrete model. Plus I don't know if CI supports abstract core classes extension.

For the solution 1, I'm not sure it can be implemented either. Let's say I define a concrete class `MY_Model` and an interface `CrudModelInterface`. I put all the attributes in `MY_Model` (they can't be in the interface), but then my CRUD methods need to use them, so `CrudModelInterface` must extend `MY_Model` right? That's where it gets fuzzy to me...

Provided that you understood what I want to do, could you please advise me about my design, how you would do it, etc. Anything constructive. Currently, I simply didn't impose the constraints to define those "interface methods", but I'm doing it in every model, so it works. It's just not very clean.

Answer (score 1):

**The recommended option** is to use the supercharged [DataMapper ORM for CodeIgniter](http://cibonfire.com/) or another ORM Library, instead of writing your own thing.

**But in answer to your direct question**, I think you don't really need an interface or abstract functions. Here's a quick example of MY_Model and another concrete model

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

   public $_table;

   public function find_all() {
        return $this->db->from($this->_table)->get()->result_object();
   }

   public function find_by_id($id, $id_field_name = 'id') {
        $this->db->where("$this->_table.$id_field_name", $id);
        $result = $this->find_all();
        return count($result) == 1 ? $result[0] : null;
   }

   public function insert($data) {
        $this->db->insert($this->_table, (array) $data);
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $id;
   }

   public function update($id, $data) {
        if ($id != null) {  // update existing record
            $updated = $this->db->update($this->_table, $data, "id = $id");
            return $updated;
        } else {            // add a new record
            $inserted = $this->insert($data);
            return $inserted;
        }
   }

   public function delete($id) {
        $deleted = $this->db->delete($this->_table, array('id' => $id), 1);
        return $deleted;
   }

    .........

}
```

Now all you gotta do in order to take the profit of MY_Model's functions is to define your model and set the $_table variable with the table name.

```
class Users_Model extends MY_Model {

    public $_table = 'users';

}
```

Obviously you can add a lot of other methods in MY_Model to further extend it. This approach come form [Bonfire](http://cibonfire.com/) which is a HMVC built on top of CodeIgniter. [See their implementation of MY_Model](https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire/blob/develop/application/core/MY_Model.php).

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. There are several things that are wrong with it (part of these reasons justify my question as well): first, the interface I talked about was not for the CRUD methods, but for the methods they rely on (typically on deletion, a method to handle the deletion of records in other tables that refer to the record deleted in the first place, this is one example). Second, passing the `$id` as an input of `find_by_id` is a bad design; doing so goes against what the model is supposed to do -- abstract the database gears on the application level.

Comment: Third, ideally, it doesn't make much sense that table names and id fieldnames would be instance variables for a given model. They should be static or constant to be identical across all instances.

Comment: Overall, my point is not that you are wrong to use your code, as I am sure it works as it should and fits your needs. My code works for me too, but my question was about the way it should be implemented using PHP features to respect its own logic, and look less like a "hack" as it does (at least to me) right now. +1 for the effort though ;)

Comment: And thanks for the +1. So what you're actually looking for is a php version of the cascade deletion of foreign keys. Have you ever looked at CI Events? You can trigger an event "user_deleted" from your user_model and that event can handle the deletion of any other data like meta data, accounts, address, contacts, etc. by loading up and calling several other models.